# Article on “strong testing not strong typing”?

Tags: unit-testing

There is a chapter in “[The Best Software Writing I: Selected and Introduced by Joel Spolsky](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590595009)” on strong testing not strong type.   I think it was based on a blog posting by someone, but I don’t have access to the book at work.

Can someone please post the link.  (It's not as easy to find on google as I would have hoped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it [this](https://docs.google.com/View?id=dcsvntt2_25wpjvbbhk) by Bruce Eckel

Answer (score 1):

this perhaps:

http://osteele.com/archives/2003/08/test-versus-type